# How to add a gradient into transparency at the border of an image with PHP Imagic

Tags: php, imagick

I am constructing a graphine, used in place of any user's photograph that does not have such. I have constructed it by using a login and transforming it into geometrical shapes on white background. All is working fine, but i would like to have gradual gradient into transparent at the border of the image.

Currently the generated image looks like

[image: already existing image]

I would like to make it be something like

[image: desired image]

The way i have produced the desired image in Gimp is:

1. Add a layer mask with full transparency
2. Select entire image
3. Feather selection by 30 px
4. Fill the layer mask with white within the selection

Can i perform similar transformations in PHP with Image Magic?

Answer (score 1):

Yes i believe so below is a sample syntax to do so
Please not that the code is not tested when I get in front of my machine I can test and review the code.

```
<?php


$imagick = new \Imagick('OxMui.png');


$width = $imagick->getImageWidth();
$height = $imagick->getImageHeight();
echo $width;
// Create a gradient mask
$gradient = new \Imagick();
$gradient->newPseudoImage($width, $height, 'gradient:rgba(255,255,255,0)-rgba(255,255,255,1)');

// Apply the gradient mask to the original image
$imagick->compositeImage($gradient, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);

$imagick->setImageFormat('png');
$imagick->writeImage('output.png');
$imagick->destroy();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does something very different. Your code makes a gradient that starts at the bottom of the image being opaque and goes into transparency as it moves up. I need almost an entire image to be opaque, and only the 30px (or some other size) border to be that gradient. See the example image in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to alter [the approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77852817/2893496) of [Oyinlade Demola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16448070/oyinlade-demola) and came up with the different way to create the mask, that suited my purpose:

```
$mask = new Imagick();
$mask->newPseudoImage(200, 200, 'canvas:transparent');
$draw = new \ImagickDraw();
$draw->setStrokeColor( new ImagickPixel( 'black' ) );
$draw->setFillColor( new ImagickPixel( 'black' ) );
$draw->roundRectangle(10, 10, 200-15, 200-15, 30, 30);
$mask->drawImage( $draw );
$mask->blurImage(30, 15);

$canvas->compositeImage($mask, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);
```

The result that i get is[image]

I wasn't aware that `COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY` exists, and that was a large part of this question, but using `gradient` is not suitable for the mask.